# Обязательно ли делать максимальный размер хэш-таблицы простым числом?

Tags: хеширование, структуры-данных

В теории прочитал, что размер хэш-таблицы должен быть простым числом, но готовые словари ЯП могут иметь чётный размер, - что я не так понял?

Comment: Это требование не обязательно. Простой размер таблицы делает ситуацию чуть лучше если хеш-функция плохая. С хорошей хеш-функцией размер может быть любым.

Comment: Спасибо! А почему это так, не подскажете?

Comment: Например, если хеш-функция выдаёт только чётные значения и хеш-таблица имеет чётный размер, нечётные корзины останутся пустыми. В более общем случае заполненость таблицы зависит от ***НОД(<период функции>, <размер таблицы>)***. Если он единица, все корзины имеют шанс заполнится, нет - нет. Так как заранее качество хеш-функции не известно (эти функции пишут программисты разной квалификации), надо так подобрать размер таблицы, чтобы был шанс на ***НОД = 1*** (период функции и размер таблицы должны быть взаимно просты). С каким размером это сделать проще всего? С простым.

Comment: Аж ответ написал. Вдруг кому полезно будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это требование не обязательно. Простой размер таблицы делает ситуацию чуть лучше если хеш-функция плохая. С хорошей хеш-функцией размер может быть любым.

Например, если хеш-функция выдаёт только чётные значения и хеш-таблица имеет чётный размер, нечётные корзины останутся пустыми. В более общем случае заполненость таблицы зависит от ***НОД(<период функции>, <размер таблицы>)***. Если он единица, все корзины имеют шанс заполнится, нет - нет. Так как заранее качество хеш-функции не известно (эти функции пишут программисты разной квалификации), надо так подобрать размер таблицы, чтобы был шанс на ***НОД = 1*** (период функции и размер таблицы должны быть взаимно просты). С каким размером это сделать проще всего? С простым.

Объяснение на пальцах, но можно подвести строгую базу почему простые размеры лучше. Повторюсь, если сама хеш-функция хорошо хеширует, размер не важен.

С другой стороны, если размер таблицы - степень двойки, то вместо деления по модулю, можно обойтись применением двоичной маски. Обращение к таблице частая операция, `hash & mask` вместо `hash % size` заметно улучшает производительность.